# Curl request stored in variable when executed using bash log failed and success urls

Tags: curl

I used chrome devtools to get copy as curl request. but when i run it some failed. so how can i log success and failed url request

i had multiple curl requests stored in file or variable

eg. code

```
var='curl -X data -H Refferer:http://something.html "url.zip"'
IFS=$'\n'
for f in `echo "$var"`;
 do
echo "$f" | bash && echo "$f" | grep -Po 'http.*html' >> success || echo "$f" | grep -Po http.*html >> fail; done
```

But failed one were not being logged.
Can someone help

Comment: I ran this code and curl said `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: url.zip`, and the file `fail` contains `http://something.html`. So what is not working? Please provide examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping the commands solves it

```
var='curl -X data -H Referrer:http://something.html "url.zip"'
IFS=$'\n'
for f in `echo "$var"`;
 do
echo "$f" | bash && { echo "$f" | grep -Po 'http.*html' >> success; } || { echo "$f" | grep -Po http.*html >> fail; }; done
```